# Get a EditText to String then show in Toast

Tags: java, android, string

I'm very new in Java and have been trying this for days now, seems that I need to profundize the bases way more, anyway, it seems that I can't get the toast right, here's the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText web;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final EditText web = findViewById(R.id.web);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String webastring = web.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText((this,web.toString(), "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, webastring, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.String, int)

Comment: use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this`

Comment: Yeah i did, it looks like your code

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, web.getText().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use MainActivity.this instead of only this. Here the 'this' represents anonymous class not MainActivity. But you have to pass main activity reference to Toast. You also put four parameters instead of three to Toast.makeText() method. So you have to pass three parameters. Here is the official link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts for showing Toast. I hope the following code will be worked fine for you.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String webstring = web.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, webstring + "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update button.setOnClickListener() method by following piece of code**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
    String webastring = web.getText().toString();     
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),webastring,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an EditText's (or any other child of TextView) contents, you have to call the function `getText()`.

So your code will be like this:

```
        Toast.makeText((this,web.getText().toString(), "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `button` `setOnClickListener` as below code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String webastring = web.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,webastring, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```